# Eclispse Install software says "Can not complete the request"

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
When I try to install new software 
It gives some error message like `Cannot complete the request. This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates.`
And my error log says

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_75
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk
Warning
Mon May 11 14:35:07 IST 2015
Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.
```

I came across similar problems in
[How to enable Software Update in an Eclipse product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414096/how-to-enable-software-update-in-an-eclipse-product)
and [Getting the message "Cannot start the update ui..." when trying to run the update UI in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023044/getting-the-message-cannot-start-the-update-ui-when-trying-to-run-the-updat/1023298?noredirect=1#comment48432988_1023298)
but it didnot solve my problem

Answer (score 9):

I hit this same error (Eclipse Mars).
Shutting down all Eclipse instances and starting with `eclipse.exe -clean` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

[Bug 378568](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378568) mentions:

> Looks like the configuration of your eclipse is damaged.
>
> Check the value of '`eclipse.p2.profile`' and '`eclipse.p2.data.area`' in `config.ini`, then check whether the specified profile can be found from path '`eclipse.p2.data.area`'.

```
<eclipse.p2.data.area>\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profile‌​Registry
```

Removing those files (in the folder `eclipse.p2.data.area`) and relaunching Eclipse should help fix the issue.
Although [FaithReaper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4537090/faithreaper) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163571/eclispse-install-software-says-can-not-complete-the-request/30165863?noredirect=1#comment77542941_30165863):

> Removing the `eclipse.p2.data.area` folder prevents Eclipse from launching.
> In my case it is `C:\Users\<my.user.name>\.p2`

The discussion mentions the error:

```
An internal error occurred during: 
"Loading bundle: 
  /eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1304/0/.cp/bundles/php.ruble". 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 
  cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

This is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111765/6309) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280148/6309)) as a patch to be applied (see [bug 445122: `ClassCastException` received when `System.getProperties().store()` runs on 4.4.1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122#c51))

> Just add the following lines to `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.home
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=null
```

Comment: I get something like `An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1304/0/.cp/bundles/php.ruble".
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: @Goutam what is the path mentioned by `eclipse.p2.data.area` in the `config.ini`?

Comment: @Goutam in that folder, do you see the file pointed out by the `eclipse.p2.profile` key from the `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: There is a folder org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine which contains an empty directory named profileRegistry

Comment: @Goutam for testing, can you try an `eclipse -clean` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030106/6309) and then try to add your lpugin again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77511/discussion-between-goutam-and-vonc).

Comment: `-clean` helped me

Comment: We should note that the file containing the key `eclipse.p2.data.area` is `<eclipse-root-dir>/configuration/config.ini`. It took me awhile to find it.

Comment: @FaithReaper Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: And another thing is, "then check whether the specified profile can be found from path `eclipse.p2.data.area` " may cause some confusion... the profile is under `<eclipse.p2.data.area>\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry`

Comment: @FaithReaper Thank you again. I have included the path, but if you see a way to make this section clearer, don't hesitate to edit it yourself: I will approve your edit.

Comment: That's enough for now. Thanks for adding my comments to make it clear. Not everyone appreciate their valid answer like you... my thanks to you.

Answer (score -3):

It worked when I put the full eclipse folder (containing the executable) at the root of the harddrive like :

C:\eclipse

Same for the workspace.

Comment: Non-detailed explanations, tips or ideas should instead be placed in comments.